What solutions are available to dynamically load native libraries on Android while following the native library namespace restrictions?
TLDR: I need to be able to dynamically create and load copies of a native library at runtime into some kind of temp or cache directory, but because of Android's native library namespace restrictions this isn't possible.
Bit of backstory: I'm developing an Android app and I make use of a native .so library. This library internally makes use of static variables, functions and so on and doesn't provide any sort of container or struct that allows me as a developer to make use of unique instances of data. (i.e the entire native library acts on singletons). This is slightly annoying as I need to be able to run the functions contained in the library multiple times with structs / classes that contain unique data to that process. My approach to handle this was to create a wrapper that essentially creates copies of the native library file in some cache/ directory under data/data/com.my.company.files at runtime as needed, and loads them into my apps memory. This way I can work around the static / singleton approach of the library.
However, I've recently discovered that from Android v7, Android is very strict about the native libraries that can be loaded (and also the number of native libraries that can be loaded by your app - which also included any system libraries loaded by Android. This to me is just an insane restriction). Any time I try loading my native library from the cache/ directory I build, I get an exception that looks like this: "Native library "libNative.so" is not is not accessible for the namespace "classloader-namespace". Which makes sense given the restriction. I don't like this restriction, as it makes my job harder, but I can see why it's been implemented. Packaging the native library as part of my apk isn't really feasible because I need to dynamically make copies at run time, unless I package like 10 copies of the library (i.e libNative_0, libNative_1 etc.) into the apk. So I'm kind of at a loss for how I can handle this situation after a lot of googling and thinking by myself on how to solve this problem.

"This is slightly annoying as I need to be able to run the functions contained in the library multiple times with structs / classes that contain unique data to that process" -- it would seem like the answer is to use multiple processes.
